# Confusion with STATIC_ROOT in DjangoProject documentation

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I have some confusion with the [DjangoProject 1.6 Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#static-root) for STATIC_ROOT

> The absolute path to the directory where collectstatic will collect
>   static files for deployment.
>
> Example: "/var/www/example.com/static/"

Does this mean

> The absolute path to the directory where collectstatic will collect
>   static files **from** for deployment.

Or does it mean

> The absolute path to the directory where collectstatic will collect
>   static files **to** for deployment.

Seems like it could be either to me which is very confusing and makes a huge difference.

Any clarification will help me stop going mad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means where collectstatic will collect static files to. Collectstatic will take all static files from different static folders (in different apps, main static directory etc.) and put them in the location specified by `STATIC_ROOT`. The fact that it collects the files *from*  various folders and *into*  a single folder, and that `STATIC_ROOT` is a single folder is a slight pointer :P

This is also in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#static-root):

> **Warning**:
>   This should be an (initially empty) destination directory for collecting your static files from their permanent locations into one directory for ease of deployment; it is not a place to store your static files permanently. You should do that in directories that will be found by staticfiles’s finders, which by default, are 'static/' app sub-directories and any directories you include in STATICFILES_DIRS).

So you should *not*  initially store your static files in the folder specified by `STATIC_ROOT`. If a file is found in another location first, the initial file in your `STATIC_ROOT` directory will be overwritten and lost when `collectstatic` is run.

Comment: Thanks. My confusion came from being recommended to point my STATIC_ROOT to the same location I store my static files during development. e.g.  `/var/www/bias_experiment/src/survey/static/survey` which dose not seem right at all

Comment: @Deepend That's a strange recommendation. See the warning in my edit and the Django documentation.